# Is there a function that will tell me which packages other R functions are in?

Tags: r, function, install.packages

How can I find what package a function is in?
I'm just learning R and sometimes know what function I want but can't remember which package it's in - is there another function or easy way to look this up? The [github cheatsheets](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/) show which functions are in a package, but I'm looking for the reverse - I've been googling but looking for a function etc. to find this. Thanks!

Comment: You can use https://rdrr.io/ or https://rdocumentation.org/

Comment: you can just use `?your_function` the only 'complication' may arise from shared namespaces but then you can still see a list of the packages which include the name of the function

Comment: The suggeston from @DJ will work if the package is loaded. Otherwise try `??your_function`.

Comment: @DJ note that `?` will only search in package you have currently loaded? You can use `??` to search packages that are locally installed but possibly not loaded. But if it's a package you've not yet installed, you'd have to look elsewhere.

Comment: @MrFlick you are correct! the way the question was posted led me to believe that the packages in question were installed already (possibly loaded). but that assumption may have been a bit too narrow

Comment: Outside of what the other commenters said, I also just use a web search, like "your_function R" and it's usually one of the top results.

Comment: also try installing the `sos` package and using the `findFn()` command.

Comment: Thank you all! It looks like @SamR's suggestion is exactly what I need as I'm trying to find functions to know which packages I need to load to use them. I didn't know about the ??your_function, just ?your_function, so appreciate the guidance. And thanks for the other suggestions - off to explore them as well!